# Was Avenue 5 abruptly cancelled?

Tags: production, cancellation, avenue-5

While I'm usually quite adverse to toilet humor, my love for satire and anything Sci-Fi got me to watch the first couple of episodes of Avenue 5. After a bit of a rocky start (IMHO), I started to appreciate the Pythonesque parody and droll humor stylings of the show despite the crude writing.

Now that the series has completed its first season with nine (...?) episodes, it seems to me that the season finale was very anticlimactic beyond transposing the location of two characters. Yes, another obstacle in their journey home was introduced but that plot point reoccurred in pretty much every episode.

Did they produce nine episodes only to have someone at the top of the food chain decide enough was enough and halt production or did they complete the planned shooting schedule and are legitimately in hiatus with a second season planned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avenue_5), the show was renewed for a second season last month.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently my google-fu was having a bad day. After following the linked footnote reference from that Wikipedia page, I was able to locate several confirming articles.